# Can't be solved using methods available

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I'm stuck on this and chagrined I'm even asking, but this:

```
NSolve[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 
  4 - 2 t^3 == s^3, -π <= s < π, -π <= t < π}, {s, t}]
```

gives `"NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve"`, or `Solve` for that matter.
Thank you

Comment: From the documentation: "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations". This is more of a problem for `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 3):

You could solve it as a minimization:

```
NMinimize[{(-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 - (4 - 2 s^3))^2 + ( 
    4 - 2 t^3 - s^3)^2, -π <= s < π, -π <= t < π}, {s, t}]
(* result: {3.16777*10^-30, {s -> 1.49116, t -> 0.699433}} *)

system = {-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 4 - 2 t^3 == s^3, -π <= s < π, -π <= t < π};
system /. {s -> 1.4911575481418087`, t -> 0.6994333479233502`}

(* result: {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 4 - 2 t^3 == s^3};
```

The exact solution for `t` is a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression

```
solt = Solve[{Eliminate[eqns, s], -π <= t < π}, t][[1]]
```

[image]

```
solt // N

(* {t -> 0.699433} *)
```

The exact solution for `s` is similarly

```
sols = Solve[{eqns[[2]] /. solt, -π <= s < π}, s][[1]]
```

[image]

```
sols // N

(* {s -> 1.49116} *)

(eqns /. solt /. sols) // N

(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Strangely, your `Solve[{t^3 == 2 Cos[2 t], -π < t < π}, t]` works but the equivalent `Solve[t^3 == 2 Cos[2 t], t]` does not work. Your solution is better than the `FindRoot` application I proposed.

Comment: @Roman - in this case, the constraint is equivalent to specifying the domain as real, i.e., `Solve[t^3 == 2 Cos[2 t], t, Reals]`

Answer (score 2):

Substitute the second equation into the first:

```
FullSimplify[-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3 /. s^3 -> 4 - 2 t^3]
(*    t^3 == 2 Cos[2 t]    *)
```

By inspection we see that there is only one solution:

```
Plot[{t^3, 2 Cos[2 t]}, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image]

Find the solution and compute $\{s,t\}$:

```
{(4 - 2 t^3)^(1/3), t} /. FindRoot[t^3 == 2 Cos[2 t], {t, 1}]
(*    {1.49116, 0.699433}    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSolve` can solve the system as complex problem:

```
csol = NSolve[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 
   4 - 2 t^3 == s^3, -π <= Re@s < π, -π <= Re@t < π,
    -1/10 < Im@s < 1/10, -1/10 < Im@t < 1/10}, {s, t}]
rsol = Chop[csol]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{s -> 1.49116 + 0. I, t -> 0.699433 + 0. I}}
>   {{s -> 1.49116, t -> 0.699433}}
> *)
> ```

*Update*

`Solve` also works if you avoid the singularity at `s == 0`:

```
Solve[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 4 - 2 t^3 == s^3,
  1 < s < 2, -π <= t < π}, {t, s}, Reals]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{t -> Root[{2 - 4 Cos[#1]^2 + #1^3 &, 0.69943334792335012145}], 
>   s -> Root[-4 + 2 Root[{2 - 4 Cos[#1]^2 + #1^3 &, 
>          0.69943334792335012145}]^3 + #1^3 &, 1]}}
> *)
> ```

Also if it is "factored" out (as a product $(s,t)\times (u)$):

```
Solve[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 u, 4 - 2 t^3 == u, u == s^3,
  -π <= s < π, -π <= t < π}, {t, s, u}, Reals]
```

> ```
> (*
> {{t -> Root[{2 - 4 Cos[#1]^2 + #1^3 &, 0.69943334792335012145}], 
>   s -> Root[-8 + 8 Cos[Root[{2 - 4 Cos[#1]^2 + #1^3 &, 
>           0.69943334792335012145}]]^2 + #1^3 &, 1], 
>   u -> 8 - 8 Cos[Root[{2 - 4 Cos[#1]^2 + #1^3 &, 
>           0.69943334792335012145}]]^2}}
> *)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ContourPlot` and  Graphics`MeshFindIntersections.

And then use `FindRoot` again.

```
Clear["`*"];
Clear["`*"];
curves = ContourPlot[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 
   4 - 2 t^3 == s^3}, {s, -π, π}, {t, -π, π}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[Tiny]], 
    Directive[Blue, Thickness[Tiny]]}, ImageSize -> Full]
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[curves[[All, 1]]]
(* {{1.49114,0.699426}} *)

FindRoot[{-12 + 16 Cos[t]^2 == 4 - 2 s^3, 4 - 2 t^3 == s^3}, {s, 
  1.49114}, {t, 0.699426}]
(* {s -> 1.49116, t -> 0.699433} *)
```

[image]